# Checking if a string is alphabetical

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

The following code is my exhausted attempt to check an inputted string for if it's in alphabetical order or not.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class order
    {
        public static void main ( String[] args )
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner ( System.in );  // Create a Scanner object
            boolean isInOrder;
            
            System.out.println ( "\n\n\n\n\n" + "<EV> \"Hello sir, please enter a string value for me ;)\" " + "\n" );
    
            String stringInput = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println ( "\n" + "<EV> \"You entered: " + stringInput + "\"");
    
            for ( int alpha = 0; alpha != stringInput.length(); ++alpha )
            {
                if ( !Character.isLetter(stringInput.charAt(alpha)))
                {
                    isInOrder = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    isInOrder = true;
                }
            }
    
            System.out.println( "<EV> \"It seems that the string you provided is...\"" + "\n" );
    
            if ( isInOrder = false )
            {
                System.out.println( "<EV> \"NOT alphabetical!\"");
            }
            else if ( isInOrder = true )
            {
                System.out.println( "<EV> \"Alphabetical!\"" + "\n");
            }
    
            System.out.println( "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
        }
    }
```

Just wondering where I'm going wrong, no errors are flagging which is even more annoying.

Comment: As soon as you find the first violation - exit your loop.

Comment: Your question is unclear. In the title you say "alphabetical" and in the text "in alphabetical order". Do you want to check if the string only contains letter or if those letters are in alphabetical order?

Comment: The way you've written your code, nothing before the `if` statement can affect the output.  The if statement you've written is equivalent to `if (false) { ... } else if (true) { ... }`.  Do you see why?  You haven't actually done any comparison.  The `=` operator performs an inline assignment, assigning `isInOrder` to whatever is to the right of the `=` symbol.  I believe you are looking for the equality operator `==`, although you could just remove the operator entirely.  `if (isInOrder) { ... } else { ... }` would be the normal way to do it.

Comment: As Charlie Armstrong said, use `if(isInOrder)` or `if(! isInOrder)` for negation. Don’t use `==` for `true` and `false`, then you can’t confuse it with `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to check if all entered input is a character/letter, I see several issues with your code

- For loop not stopped if invalid input is found: Because you keep looping in the for loop, even when you find a wrong input, the `isInOrder` boolean will always contain the result of the final character
- Your if check in the end is validating that you can assign the value false or true to the variable. You need to use `==` here instead of `=`
- Checking for `isInOrder == false` makes the code harder to read, and the comparison is quite useless. You could just put your check immediate. Within the if part, you just need to have a boolean result, which `isInOrder` already returns for you. `if(isInOrder){<true part>} else {<false part>}`

Code for the loop could look like this

```
    for (int alpha = 0; alpha != stringInput.length(); ++alpha) {
        if (!Character.isLetter(stringInput.charAt(alpha))) {
            isInOrder = false;
            break;
        } else {
            isInOrder = true;
        }
    }
```

### Optimalisation

A suggestion to make this loop a lot shorter is to make use of Streams. You could use the `allMatch` method to validate that all elements in the passed string are letters. As soon as one is not, this will stop calculating and return you the result.

```
isInOrder = stringInput.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter);
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if all the characters in the string are letters using loop:

```java
boolean allLetters = true;

for (char c : alpha.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(c)) {
        allLetters = false;
    }
}
```

This may also be verified simply using method `String::matches` with a regular expression:

```java
boolean allLetters = alpha.matches("\\p{L}+"); // check any letters
// or alpha.matches("\\p{Alpha}+"); for Latin letters only
```

---

To check that all the characters are in alphabetic order that is `c0 <= c1 <= c2 ... <= cN`:

```java
boolean inOrder = true;
for (int i = 1, n = alpha.length(); i < n; i++) {
    if (alpha.charAt(i - 1) > alpha.charAt(i)) { // order broken
        inOrder = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `n = alpha.length()` and `i < n` instead of `i < alpha.length()`?

Comment: It's a sort of cached value for the string length, to avoid invocation of `String::length` on each iteration.

Comment: Are you using a deactivated JIT?

Comment: No, just out of habit.

Comment: @Tom for some collections or similar data structures it may may a difference, i.e. if `length()` or `size()`, etc. are not a cheap operation, but you only need to configure your IDE’s templates once, to always use the same pattern.

Comment: Another alternative: `alpha.chars().allMatch(Character::isLetter)`.

Comment: This was provided in @Yoni's answer 20 hours ago :)